# TYPO3: How to fix install issue

Tags: php, typo3, installation, typo3-10.x

I have a problem installing TYPO3 10.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Apache 2.4.29, PHP 7.2

I did follow the "Install TYPO3 Without Composer" How to. When I want to access the Installer I see a blank page. So far nothing new, I have seen that a lot of times. I did set the access rights correct but still a blank page.

The Apache error log says:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
LogicException:PSR-11 Container is not available in
/var/www/typo3_src/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php:3398
```

In the mentioned php I see additional information `'PSR-11 Container is not available', 1549404144`.

I did search on the web to find a possible solution but this time without any luck.

My question: Did someone see that bevore or has a hnt for me what to do?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Dabbelju

Comment: Are you able to obtain a stack trace? You should find it in the log file in `typo3temp/var/log/` (without composer) or `var/log` (with composer) - that would help to see which code tries to access a container which was not created before.

Comment: I stumbled upon a similar error recently - my problem was that the log directory could not be created and the log file was not writable (the error message was highly misleading as that is a subsequent error of the file access problem). Try creating the log directory yourself (see Jonas answer) and set the access rights.

Comment: Jonas, Susi, thanks for your reply. It is my first post on stackoverflow so I hope I did handle it in the correct way. @Jonas: No, I can not. The folder is empty. I have faced the situation Susi described before. The first error mesage was, that /typo3temp/var/log/ could noit be created. I did what Susi suggested and die set the Userrights to the mentioned folder to root:www-data (I know that root is not the best way, but it is just a test server before I do it on live system). I will delete the folder again and chase the problem why it can not be created. Update will follow.

Comment: I have found the problem. And even if it is embarrissing for me: It was a permission problem. I have a folder /var/www/website which contains symbolic links to the typo3 src. The access rights for /website/ was wrong. Thanks for your hints. I did guide me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem (Installation with composer by the way).
The problem is that the web server does not have the needed access rights on the Typo3 project folder.
When using the Apache HTTP Server this can be solved with

```sh
chown -R :www-data YourProjectFolder  
chmod -R g+w YourProjectFolder
```

This recursively changes the group of all contained files to 'www-data' which is the group used by the Apache server and grants write access for this group.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap this one up:

It was a permission problem. Due to the missleading Error message it took me a while to figure that out. In the mentioned [guide](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html) it does not say something about permissions.

My conclusion: Whenever it comes to the point that T3 says that a folder can not be created fix the permission problem instead of adding the folder manually.

Thanks to all who did guide me to the right solution.